# Ruby on Rails - Devise sign up link not working - undefined method `user_registration_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This issue has been previously reported, but I still have not been able to find a fix for it.

I have installed the plugin Devise on to my new RoR project. When I click on the sign up link, I am redirected to the following route:

http://localhost:3000/users/registration/sign_up

However, I obtain the following error:

```
undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd5d3503d58>:0x007fd5d3b0dcd0>
```

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2:   <h1>Sign up</h1>
3: </div>
4: 
5: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
6:   <%= f.error_notification %>
7: 
8:   <div class="inputs">
```

My routes produces the following:

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
            password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create {:name_prefix=>:user}
        new_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new {:name_prefix=>:user}
       edit_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit {:name_prefix=>:user}
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update {:name_prefix=>:user}
                     POST   /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#create {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                 new GET    /users/registration/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                edit GET    /users/registration/edit(.:format)    devise/registrations#edit {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                     PUT    /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#update {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
                     DELETE /users/registration(.:format)         devise/registrations#destroy {:name_prefix=>"user_registration"}
          home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                 home#index
               users GET    /users(.:format)                      users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                      users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                  users#new
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)             users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                  users#show
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                  users#update
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                  users#destroy
                root        /                                     home#index
```

My routes.rb has the following code:

```
 devise_for :users

  get "home/index"

  resources :users
  root :to => "home#index"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is created when the devise version is 1.1.0 RC and you are running Rails 3.

Please look on how to upgrade your devise gem:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue and restarting the rails server fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:  I think you have to specify the "METHOD" as "POST" of the form.

```
5: <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
6:    :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
7:    :method => :POST) do |f| %>
```

================  (deprecated answer below)

I think you have problems in your config/routes.rb file.   the expected output is :

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)          devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)     devise/registrations#edit
```

so make sure your config/routes.rb has this linke of code:

```
devise_for :users
```

Comment: My routes.rb has the devise_for :users. Ive edited my question to include routes.rb. Any idea?

Comment: It was the version of devise! I was using 1.1.0 RC

Comment: Thanks for your answer tho :) the difference in your routes.rb pointed me out that something might have been wrong with my devise gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might be help:
if you mentioned any devise gem version remove that and keep only gem 'devise' and type bundle update command in terminal.