# devise error on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Im getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x10f227cd8>:0x10f5f6d50>
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1: <h2>Sign up</h2>
2: 
3: <%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <%= f.error_messages %>
5:   <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
6:   <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
```

I checked everything and i didnt found an error, i had just created the project and installed the plugin.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762908/ruby-on-rails-devise-sign-up-link-not-working-undefined-method-user-registr)

Answer (score 0):

I was using a old version of the devise plugin in the new version of the ror. =x